# ASP.NET MVC - Having a confirmation button with a Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an strongly typed view for my model and what I'd like is that when the user clicks on submit, a confirmation box pop up confirming that the user does indeed wish to submit the form, if they click cancel then it shouldn't fire the `HttpPost` Action for that View, is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Of course it is possible. I like to use an unobtrusive approach. Here is a simplified example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('[data-confirm]').click(function (e) {
    if (!confirm(jQuery(this).attr("data-confirm")))
    {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Then you only need to add a data-confirm attribute to your submit button for example

```
<input type="submit" data-confirm="are u sure?" />
```

Of course you can use this attribute on links, buttons, etc. you are not restricted to submit buttons only, and if you want to implement a fancier confirm dialog later than you will have to replace the code only in one place.

Comment: I have <form name="Form1" method="post" action="@Url.Action("PostForm", "Job")"  id="Form1"> as my form action and none of the solutions I tried work. They all show a confirmation dialogue but then dont submit the form data if you click "yes". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to create a separate question including all the related information. If you take the effort to create a jsfiddle and include the link in your question you will get an answer in no time.

Answer (score 5):

you can add a simply jQuery call for that.

at the end of your view add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("form").submit(function() {

        return confirm('Are you sure?');

    });

</script>
```

or, add a

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

as a new element property

Answer (score 5):

```
        function doSubmit()
        {                                 
                if(window.confirm("ARE YOU SURE TO PERFORM THIS ACTION"))
                {                       
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;                
        }
```

call `doSubmit()` function on `onsubmit` event of the form, 
Eg- `onsubmit="return doSubmit()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done by overriding the submit button using jquery. [Jquery .submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

This way, when the person hits submit you can show a message and either submit it or cancel it.